# Listview Cursor adapter with section header

Tags: android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I'm working on an IM application. In that I'm using listview to show the buddies list with the help of custom cursor adapter. I'd like to add section header as like contacts application display.Which is the best way of doing it without adding any new library for that?